# Can I manage NuGet references without a project or solution file?

Tags: nuget

I want to manage some NuGet references in a `packages.config` file (or similar) that is NOT tied to any project/solution. I need the following operations:

1. Add a reference to the `packages.config` file

   - (All its dependencies should be added automatically - the same way it works in VS in the context of a project.)
2. Install all references in the `packages.config` file

I can easily do #2 by running `nuget install packages.config`, but I cannot figure out #1. Is this possible?

**What I tried**

I checked [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-install):

> The `install` command does not modify a project file or `packages.config`; in this way it's similar to `restore` in that it only adds packages to disk but does not change a project's dependencies.
>
> To add a dependency, either add a package through the Package Manager UI or Console in Visual Studio, or modify `packages.config` and then run either `install` or `restore`.

I tried `nuget install <package>`. This command installs the package with its dependencies, but it does not update `packages.config`.

I tried adding a reference to `packages.config` in a text editor. That works for the direct reference, but NuGet doesn't know to install the required dependencies. (I could manually add the dependencies, but that is cumbersome.)

I tried using the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio, but it complains "The current environment doesn't have a solution open."

I tried using the Package Manager UI in Visual Studio, but I don't see any way to open that without a project/solution.

Comment: NuGet is the package management system designed for .NET projects. There might be some hacky ways of using NuGet without a .NET project or solution, but I suppose they are not supported. Therefore I'd discourage you from doing so.

Comment: My question is "is this possible" not "do you approve of my doing this." I have found official commands that do _almost_ everything I need. So I'm hoping there is some way to solve the last problem that is blocking me.